# Get all categories

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to create a list of all the categories exist for my custom post type.

For each category i would like to create a Category Name Link.

Could anyone help me in this loop?

Comment: do you want categories that are only associated to that specific type, excluding categories associated to other post types?

Comment: [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) What have you tried?

Comment: Actually I need to list all the categories of products created by WooCommerce plugin.

Comment: Additional info in an [edit] please

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wp_list_categories` function with the taxonomy argument `product_cat`:

```
<ul class="categories">
     <?php wp_list_categories( 'taxonomy=product_cat&title_li=' ) ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TheDeadMedic, but I just wanted the name of the categories.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo $term->name . '<br />';
}
```

And I got using the [get_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)